# Programmatically determine allowed values for Azure HDInsight definition/template

Tags: c#, azure

I am attempting to create HDInsight clusters using the Microsoft.Azure.Management.HDInsight package. The client is the HDInsightManagementClient which accepts an object Models.ClusterCreateParametersExtended.

```
    Context.HDInsightManagementClient.Clusters.Create
        (
        clusterParameters.resourceGroupName,
        clusterParameters.clusterName,
        parameters
        );
```

ClusterCreateParametersExtended requires values like ClusterVersion, ClusterDefinition.Kind, ClusterDefinition.ComponentVersion, and Role[n].HardwareProfile.VmSize.

```
var parameters = new ClusterCreateParametersExtended
{
...
      Properties = new ClusterCreateProperties
      {
           ClusterVersion = "3.6",
           OsType = OSType.Linux,
           ClusterDefinition = new ClusterDefinition
           {
               Kind = "Hadoop",
           ...
```

Is there an API to return allowable values for these parameters ?
(Typically allowable values are constrained by ClusterDefinition.Kind)

Answer (score 0):

The Location API can be used. See the list Functions in part one of this post.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.HDInsight;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.HDInsight.Models;
using Microsoft.Rest.Azure;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

//https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/hdinsight?view=azure-dotnet
//https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-azure/index.html
namespace hdiMgmt
{
    public class ClusterOperations : OperationsBase
    {
        public ClusterOperations(OperationsContext context) :
            base(context)
        {
        }

        static AzureOperationResponse<CapabilitiesResult> _HDInsightCapabilities = null;

        private async Task<AzureOperationResponse<CapabilitiesResult>> HDInsightCapabilities()
        {
            if (_HDInsightCapabilities == null)
            {
                _HDInsightCapabilities = await Context.HDInsightManagementClient.Locations.GetCapabilitiesWithHttpMessagesAsync("EAST US");
            }
            return _HDInsightCapabilities;
        }

        public void ClusterCreateExtended(ClusterParameters clusterParameters)
        {
            Context.Logger.LogInformation($"Creating Cluster Extended:{clusterParameters.resourceGroupName}:{clusterParameters.clusterName}");

            var storageAccount = clusterParameters.storageAccountName + ".blob.core.windows.net";
            var container = "default";

            var parameters = new ClusterCreateParametersExtended
            {
                Location = clusterParameters.location,
                Tags = clusterParameters.tags,
                Identity = new ClusterIdentity(tenantId: "38af2d19-d06c-4caa-89fa-47ebe29e92cd")
                {
                    Type = ResourceIdentityType.UserAssigned,
                    UserAssignedIdentities = new Dictionary<string, ClusterIdentityUserAssignedIdentitiesValue>()
                    {
                        { "/subscriptions/b004cfbe-3a76-499d-a610-211305c7252c/resourcegroups/cfaromaniarg/providers/microsoft.managedidentity/userassignedidentities/romaniacluster_mi" , new ClusterIdentityUserAssignedIdentitiesValue
                            (
                                principalId: "14465063-5d78-4eff-8036-f9a74d430e73"
                            )
                        }
                    }
                },

                Properties = new ClusterCreateProperties
                {
                    ClusterVersion = "3.6",
                    OsType = OSType.Linux,
                    ClusterDefinition = new ClusterDefinition
                    {
                        Kind = "Hadoop",
                        ComponentVersion = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                        {

                        },
                        Configurations = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>()
                        {
                            { "gateway", new Dictionary<string, string>
                                {
                                    { "restAuthCredential.isEnabled", "true" },
                                    { "restAuthCredential.username", clusterParameters.clusterLoginUserName},
                                    { "restAuthCredential.password", clusterParameters.clusterLoginPassword}
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    Tier = Tier.Standard,
                    ComputeProfile = new ComputeProfile
                    {
                    Roles = new List<Role>{
                        new Role
                        {
                            Name = "headnode",
                            TargetInstanceCount = 2,
                            HardwareProfile = new HardwareProfile
                            {
                                VmSize = "standard_d12_v2"
                            },
                            OsProfile = new OsProfile
                            {
                                LinuxOperatingSystemProfile = new LinuxOperatingSystemProfile
                                {
                                    Username = clusterParameters.clusterLoginUserName,
                                    Password = clusterParameters.clusterLoginPassword
                                }
                            },
                            VirtualNetworkProfile = new VirtualNetworkProfile()
                            {
                                Id = "/subscriptions/b004cfbe-3a76-499d-a610-211305c7252c/resourceGroups/NetworkingEastUSSpoke-DS/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/DevVnetDSRM",
                                Subnet = "/subscriptions/b004cfbe-3a76-499d-a610-211305c7252c/resourceGroups/NetworkingEastUSSpoke-DS/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/DevVnetDSRM/subnets/CfsDsSubnet02"
                            }
                        },
                        new Role
                        {
                            Name = "workernode",
                            TargetInstanceCount = 3,
                            HardwareProfile = new HardwareProfile
                            {
                                VmSize = "standard_d12_v2"
                            },
                            OsProfile = new OsProfile
                            {
                                LinuxOperatingSystemProfile = new LinuxOperatingSystemProfile
                                {
                                    Username = clusterParameters.clusterLoginUserName,
                                    Password = clusterParameters.clusterLoginPassword
                                }
                            },
                            VirtualNetworkProfile = new VirtualNetworkProfile()
                            {
                                Id = "/subscriptions/b004cfbe-3a76-499d-a610-211305c7252c/resourceGroups/NetworkingEastUSSpoke-DS/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/DevVnetDSRM",
                                Subnet = "/subscriptions/b004cfbe-3a76-499d-a610-211305c7252c/resourceGroups/NetworkingEastUSSpoke-DS/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/DevVnetDSRM/subnets/CfsDsSubnet02"
                            }
                            },
                        new Role
                        {
                            Name = "zookeepernode",
                            TargetInstanceCount = 3,
                            HardwareProfile = new HardwareProfile
                            {
                                VmSize = "standard_d12_v2"
                            },
                            OsProfile = new OsProfile
                            {
                                LinuxOperatingSystemProfile = new LinuxOperatingSystemProfile
                                {
                                    Username = clusterParameters.clusterLoginUserName,
                                    Password = clusterParameters.clusterLoginPassword
                                }
                            },
                            VirtualNetworkProfile = new VirtualNetworkProfile()
                            {
                                Id = "/subscriptions/b004cfbe-3a76-499d-a610-211305c7252c/resourceGroups/NetworkingEastUSSpoke-DS/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/DevVnetDSRM",
                                Subnet = "/subscriptions/b004cfbe-3a76-499d-a610-211305c7252c/resourceGroups/NetworkingEastUSSpoke-DS/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/DevVnetDSRM/subnets/CfsDsSubnet02"
                            }
                        },
                    }
                },
                StorageProfile = new StorageProfile
                {
                    Storageaccounts = new[]
                    {
                        new StorageAccount
                        {
                            Name = storageAccount,
                            Key = clusterParameters.storageAccountKey,
                            Container = clusterParameters.clusterName,// container,// $"{clusterParameters.resourceGroupName}--{clusterParameters.clusterName}",
                            IsDefault = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };


        try
        {
            Context.HDInsightManagementClient.Clusters.Create
                (
                clusterParameters.resourceGroupName,
                clusterParameters.clusterName,
                parameters
                );
        }
        catch (ErrorResponseException ex)
        {
            Context.Logger.LogError(ex.Body.Message);
            Context.Logger.LogError( ex.Response.Content);
            Context.Logger.LogError(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }

        public void ClusterCreate(ClusterParameters clusterParameters)
        {
            Context.Logger.LogInformation($"Creating Cluster:{clusterParameters.resourceGroupName}:{clusterParameters.clusterName}");

            var storageAccount = clusterParameters.storageAccountName + ".blob.core.windows.net";
            var container = "default";

            var parameters = new ClusterCreateParameters
            {
                Location = clusterParameters.location,


                UserName = clusterParameters.clusterLoginUserName,
                Password = clusterParameters.clusterLoginPassword,
                SshUserName = clusterParameters.sshUserName,
                SshPassword = clusterParameters.sshPassword,

                ClusterSizeInNodes = clusterParameters.ClusterSizeInNodes,
                ClusterType = clusterParameters.clusterKind,
                Version = clusterParameters.clusterVersion,

                DefaultStorageInfo = new AzureStorageInfo(storageAccount, clusterParameters.storageAccountKey, container),

                HeadNodeSize = "2"

                // OSType = "Linux",
                //// ClusterTier = Tier.Standard


                //// //DiskEncryptionProperties = new DiskEncryptionProperties().


                //// //HiveMetastore = new Metastore(AzureSqlServerName, "hive", AzureSqlUserName, AzureSqlPassword),
                //// //OozieMetastore = new Metastore(AzureSqlServerName, "oozie", AzureSqlUserName, AzureSqlPassword)
            };

            //set tags
            foreach (var item in clusterParameters.tags)
            {
                parameters.Tags.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
            }

            //set cluster identity
            var userAssignedIdentities = new Dictionary<string, ClusterIdentityUserAssignedIdentitiesValue>();
            var clusterIdentityUserAssignedIdentitiesValue = new ClusterIdentityUserAssignedIdentitiesValue
                (
                    principalId: "14465063-5d78-4eff-8036-f9a74d430e73",
                    clientId: "/subscriptions/b004cfbe-3a76-499d-a610-211305c7252c/resourcegroups/cfaromaniarg/providers/microsoft.managedidentity/userassignedidentities/romaniacluster_mi"
                );

            userAssignedIdentities.Add("default", clusterIdentityUserAssignedIdentitiesValue);

            parameters.ClusterIdentity = new ClusterIdentity
                (
                    type: ResourceIdentityType.UserAssigned,
                    tenantId: "38af2d19-d06c-4caa-89fa-47ebe29e92cd",
                    userAssignedIdentities: userAssignedIdentities
                );

            //create cluster
            try
            {
                Context.HDInsightManagementClient.Clusters.Create
                    (
                    clusterParameters.resourceGroupName,
                    clusterParameters.clusterName,
                    parameters
                    );
            }
            catch (ErrorResponseException ex)
            {
                Context.Logger.LogError(ex, ex.Body.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }

        public void ClusterCreate_Works(ClusterParameters clusterParameters)
        {
            Context.Logger.LogInformation($"Creating Cluster:{clusterParameters.resourceGroupName}:{clusterParameters.clusterName}");

            var storageAccount = clusterParameters.storageAccountName + ".blob.core.windows.net";
            var container = "default";

            var parameters = new ClusterCreateParameters
            {
                Location = clusterParameters.location,

                UserName = clusterParameters.clusterLoginUserName,
                Password = clusterParameters.clusterLoginPassword,
                SshUserName = clusterParameters.sshUserName,
                SshPassword = clusterParameters.sshPassword,

                ClusterSizeInNodes = clusterParameters.ClusterSizeInNodes,
                ClusterType = clusterParameters.clusterKind,
                Version = clusterParameters.clusterVersion,

                DefaultStorageInfo = new AzureStorageInfo(storageAccount, clusterParameters.storageAccountKey, container),


                // OSType = "Linux",
                //// ClusterTier = Tier.Standard


                //// //DiskEncryptionProperties = new DiskEncryptionProperties().


                //// //HiveMetastore = new Metastore(AzureSqlServerName, "hive", AzureSqlUserName, AzureSqlPassword),
                //// //OozieMetastore = new Metastore(AzureSqlServerName, "oozie", AzureSqlUserName, AzureSqlPassword)
            };

            try
            {
                Context.HDInsightManagementClient.Clusters.Create
                    (
                    clusterParameters.resourceGroupName,
                    clusterParameters.clusterName,
                    parameters
                    );
            }
            catch (ErrorResponseException ex)
            {
                Context.Logger.LogError(ex, ex.Body.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> ListClusterKinds()
        {
            var hDInsightCapabilities = await HDInsightCapabilities();

            var items = hDInsightCapabilities.Body.Versions.Values.SelectMany(a => a.Available)
                            .SelectMany(c => c.ComponentVersions.Keys).Distinct();
            return items;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> ListComponentVersions(string clusterKind)
        {

            var hDInsightCapabilities = await HDInsightCapabilities();

            var items = hDInsightCapabilities.Body.Versions.Values.SelectMany(a => a.Available)
                            .SelectMany(c => c.ComponentVersions)
                            .Where(c => c.Key == clusterKind)
                                .Select(v => v.Value)
                                    .Select(v => v.Split(','))
                                    .SelectMany(v => v)
                                    .Distinct();

            return items;

        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> ListClusterVersions(string clusterKind, string componentVersion)
        {

            var hDInsightCapabilities = await HDInsightCapabilities();

            var availables = hDInsightCapabilities.Body.Versions.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Available);
            var filtered = new List<VersionSpec>();

            foreach (var available in availables)
            {
                foreach (var componentVersionItem in available.ComponentVersions)
                {
                    if (componentVersionItem.Key == clusterKind)
                    {
                        if (componentVersionItem.Value.Split(',').Contains(componentVersion))
                        {
                            filtered.Add(available);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            var items = from f in filtered select f.FriendlyName;
            return items;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> ListVMSizes(string region, string clusterFlavor, string clusterVersion, ClusterNodeType clusterNodeType)
        {
            var hDInsightCapabilities = await HDInsightCapabilities();

 
            var regionName = hDInsightCapabilities.Body.Regions.Where(k => k.Key == "iaas")
                    .SelectMany(x => x.Value.Available)
                        .Where(r => r == region)
                            .FirstOrDefault();

            var vmSizes = hDInsightCapabilities.Body.VmSizes.Where(v => v.Key == "iaas")
                    .SelectMany(x => x.Value.Available).Distinct();

            var filters = hDInsightCapabilities.Body.VmSizeFilters
                    .Where(r => r.Regions.Contains("*") || r.Regions.Contains(regionName, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                        .Where(f => f.ClusterFlavors.Contains("*") || f.ClusterFlavors.Contains(clusterFlavor, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                           .Where(v => v.ClusterVersions.Contains("*") || v.ClusterVersions.Contains(clusterVersion, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                                .Where(n => n.NodeTypes.Contains("*") || n.NodeTypes.Contains(clusterNodeType.ToString() + "Role", StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                                    .Where(n => n.FilterMode == "Exclude");

            var excludedVmSizes = filters.SelectMany(v => v.Vmsizes).Distinct().ToList();

            var items = vmSizes.Where(x => excludedVmSizes.Contains(x, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == false);

            return items;
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A json file can be had by using the portal with network monitoring (F12) in Edge

```
{
    "versions": {
        "paas": {
            "available": []
        },
        "iaas": {
            "available": [{
                "friendlyName": "3.5",
                "displayName": "Version 3.5.1000.0.1910030544",
                "isDefault": false,
                "componentVersions": {
                    "HDP": "2.5"
                }
            },
            {
                "friendlyName": "3.6",
                "displayName": "Version 3.6.1000.67.2006100202",
                "isDefault": true,
                "componentVersions": {
                    "HDP": "2.6",
                    "Hadoop": "2.7.3",
                    "HBase": "1.1.2",
                    "Storm": "1.1.0",
                    "Spark": "2.1,2.2,2.3",
                    "RServer": "9.1",
                    "Kafka": "1.0.0,1.1.0",
                    "InteractiveHive": "2.1.0",
                    "MLServices": "9.3"
                }
            },
            {
                "friendlyName": "4.0",
                "displayName": "Version 4.0.2000.1.2003150128",
                "isDefault": false,
                "componentVersions": {
                    "HDP": "3.0",
                    "Hadoop": "3.1.0",
                    "HBase": "2.1.6",
                    "InteractiveHive": "3.1.0",
                    "Kafka": "1.1.0,2.1.1",
                    "Spark": "2.3,2.4"
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "regions": {
        "paas": {
            "available": ["AUSTRALIA EAST",
            "AUSTRALIA SOUTHEAST",
            "BRAZIL SOUTH",
            "CENTRAL INDIA",
            "CENTRAL US",
            "EAST ASIA",
            "EAST US 2",
            "JAPAN EAST",
            "JAPAN WEST",
            "NORTH CENTRAL US",
            "NORTH EUROPE",
            "SOUTH CENTRAL US",
            "SOUTHEAST ASIA",
            "WEST EUROPE",
            "WEST US",
            "WEST US 2"]
        },
        "iaas": {
            "available": ["AUSTRALIA EAST",
            "AUSTRALIA SOUTHEAST",
            "BRAZIL SOUTH",
            "CANADA CENTRAL",
            "CANADA EAST",
            "CENTRAL INDIA",
            "CENTRAL US",
            "CENTRAL US EUAP",
            "EAST ASIA",
            "EAST US",
            "EAST US 2",
            "JAPAN EAST",
            "JAPAN WEST",
            "NORTH CENTRAL US",
            "NORTH EUROPE",
            "SOUTH CENTRAL US",
            "SOUTH INDIA",
            "SOUTHEAST ASIA",
            "WEST CENTRAL US",
            "WEST EUROPE",
            "WEST US",
            "WEST US 2"]
        }
    },
    "vmsizes": {
        "paas": {
            "available": ["A5",
            "A6",
            "A7",
            "EXTRALARGE",
            "LARGE",
            "MEDIUM",
            "SMALL",
            "STANDARD_D1",
            "STANDARD_D1_V2",
            "STANDARD_D11",
            "STANDARD_D11_V2",
            "STANDARD_D12",
            "STANDARD_D12_V2",
            "STANDARD_D13",
            "STANDARD_D13_V2",
            "STANDARD_D14",
            "STANDARD_D14_V2",
            "STANDARD_D2",
            "STANDARD_D2_V2",
            "STANDARD_D3",
            "STANDARD_D3_V2",
            "STANDARD_D4",
            "STANDARD_D4_V2",
            "STANDARD_D5_V2"]
        },
        "iaas": {
            "available": ["A5",
            "A6",
            "A7",
            "STANDARD_A1_V2",
            "STANDARD_A10",
            "STANDARD_A11",
            "STANDARD_A2_V2",
            "STANDARD_A2m_V2",
            "STANDARD_A4_V2",
            "STANDARD_A4m_V2",
            "STANDARD_A5",
            "STANDARD_A6",
            "STANDARD_A7",
            "STANDARD_A8",
            "STANDARD_A8_V2",
            "STANDARD_A8m_V2",
            "STANDARD_A9",
            "STANDARD_D1",
            "STANDARD_D1_V2",
            "STANDARD_D11",
            "STANDARD_D11_V2",
            "STANDARD_D12",
            "STANDARD_D12_V2",
            "STANDARD_D13",
            "STANDARD_D13_V2",
            "STANDARD_D14",
            "STANDARD_D14_V2",
            "STANDARD_D2",
            "STANDARD_D2_V2",
            "STANDARD_D3",
            "STANDARD_D3_V2",
            "STANDARD_D4",
            "STANDARD_D4_V2",
            "STANDARD_D5_V2",
            "STANDARD_DS1_V2",
            "STANDARD_DS11_V2",
            "STANDARD_DS12_V2",
            "STANDARD_DS13_V2",
            "STANDARD_DS14_V2",
            "STANDARD_DS2_V2",
            "STANDARD_DS3_V2",
            "STANDARD_DS4_V2",
            "STANDARD_DS5_V2",
            "STANDARD_E16_V3",
            "STANDARD_E2_V3",
            "STANDARD_E20_V3",
            "STANDARD_E20S_V3",
            "STANDARD_E2S_V3",
            "STANDARD_E32_V3",
            "STANDARD_E4_V3",
            "STANDARD_E64_V3",
            "STANDARD_E64I_V3",
            "STANDARD_E64IS_V3",
            "STANDARD_E8_V3",
            "STANDARD_F1",
            "STANDARD_F16",
            "STANDARD_F2",
            "STANDARD_F4",
            "STANDARD_F8"]
        }
    },
    "vmsize_filters": [{
        "FilterMode": "Exclude",
        "Regions": ["*"],
        "ClusterFlavors": ["Sandbox"],
        "NodeTypes": ["*"],
        "ClusterVersions": ["*"],
        "OsType": ["*"],
        "VMSizes": ["A5"],
        "ESPApplied": null
    },
    {
        "FilterMode": "Exclude",
        "Regions": ["*"],
        "ClusterFlavors": ["*"],
        "NodeTypes": ["HeadNodeRole",
        "WorkerNodeRole",
        "EdgeNodeRole"],
        "ClusterVersions": ["*"],
        "OsType": ["*"],
        "VMSizes": ["A5"],
        "ESPApplied": null
    },
    {
        "FilterMode": "Exclude",
        "Regions": ["*"],
        "ClusterFlavors": ["*"],
        "NodeTypes": ["*"],
        "ClusterVersions": ["1.6",
        "2.1",
        "3.0"],
        "OsType": ["*"],
        "VMSizes": ["A5"],
        "ESPApplied": null
    },
    {
        "FilterMode": "Exclude",
        "Regions": ["*"],
        "ClusterFlavors": ["InteractiveHive"],
        "NodeTypes": ["HeadNodeRole",
        "WorkerNodeRole"],
        "ClusterVersions": ["*"],
        "OsType": ["*"],
        "VMSizes": ["A5"],
        "ESPApplied": null
    },
    {
        "FilterMode": "Exclude",
        "Regions": ["*"],
        "ClusterFlavors": ["*"],
        "NodeTypes": ["HeadNodeRole"],
        "ClusterVersions": ["*"],
        "OsType": ["*"],
        "VMSizes": ["A5"],
        "ESPApplied": "true"
    },
    {
        "FilterMode": "Exclude",
        "Regions": ["*"],
        "ClusterFlavors": ["Sandbox"],
        "NodeTypes": ["*"],
        "ClusterVersions": ["*"],
        "OsType": ["*"],
        "VMSizes": ["A6"],
        "ESPApplied": null
    },
    {
        "FilterMode": "Exclude",
        "Regions": ["*"],
        "ClusterFlavors": ["*"],
        "NodeTypes": ["*"],
        "ClusterVersions": ["1.6",
        "2.1",
        "3.0"],
        "OsType": ["*"],
        "VMSizes": ["A6"],
        "ESPApplied": null
    },
    {
        "FilterMode": "Exclude",
        "Regions": ["*"],
        "ClusterFlavors": ["InteractiveHive"],
        "NodeTypes": ["HeadNodeRole",
        "WorkerNodeRole"],
        "ClusterVersions": ["*"],
        "OsType": ["*"],
        "VMSizes": ["A6"],
        "ESPApplied": null
    },
    {
        "FilterMode": "Exclude",
        "Regions": ["*"],
        "ClusterFlavors": ["*"],
        "NodeTypes": ["HeadNodeRole"],
        "ClusterVersions": ["*"],
        "OsType": ["*"],
        "VMSizes": ["A6"],
        "ESPApplied": "true"
    },
    {
        "FilterMode": "Exclude",
        "Regions": ["*"],
        "ClusterFlavors": ["Sandbox"],
        "NodeTypes": ["*"],
        "ClusterVersions": ["*"],
        "OsType": ["*"],
        "VMSizes": ["A7"],
        "ESPApplied": null
    },
    {
        "FilterMode": "Exclude",
        "Regions": ["*"],
        "ClusterFlavors": ["*"],
        "NodeTypes": ["*"],
        "ClusterVersions": ["1.6",
        "2.1",
        "3.0"],
        "OsType": ["*"],
        "VMSizes": ["A7"],
        "ESPApplied": null
    },
    {
        "FilterMode": "Exclude",
        "Regions": ["*"],
        "ClusterFlavors": ["InteractiveHive"],
        "NodeTypes": ["HeadNodeRole",
        "WorkerNodeRole"],
        "ClusterVersions": ["*"],
        "OsType": ["*"],
        "VMSizes": ["A7"],
        "ESPApplied": null
    },
    {
        "FilterMode": "Exclude",
        "Regions": ["*"],
        "ClusterFlavors": ["*"],
        "NodeTypes": ["HeadNodeRole"],
        "ClusterVersions": ["*"],
        "OsType": ["*"],
        "VMSizes": ["A7"],
        "ESPApplied": "true"
    },
    {
        "FilterMode": "Exclude",
        "Regions": ["*"],
        "ClusterFlavors": ["Sandbox"],
        "NodeTypes": ["*"],
        "ClusterVersions": ["*"],
        "OsType": ["*"],
        "VMSizes": ["EXTRALARGE"],
        "ESPApplied": null
    },
    {
        "FilterMode": "Exclude",
        "Regions": ["*"],
        "ClusterFlavors": ["*"],
        "NodeTypes": ["WorkerNodeRole",
        "EdgeNodeRole",
        "ZookeeperRole"],
        "ClusterVersions": ["1.6",
        "2.1",
        "3.0"],
        "OsType": ["*"],
        "VMSizes": ["EXTRALARGE"],
        "ESPApplied": null
    },
    {
        "FilterMode": "Exclude",
        "Regions": ["*"],
        "ClusterFlavors": ["InteractiveHive"],
        "NodeTypes": ["HeadNodeRole",
        "WorkerNodeRole"],
        "ClusterVersions": ["*"],
        "OsType": ["*"],
        "VMSizes": ["EXTRALARGE"],
        "ESPApplied": null
    },
```

...TRUNCATED FOR SIZE